# How to stop openconnect from changing DNS settings

Tags: fedora, dns, resolv.conf, cisco, openconnect

Since my college is using this horrible Cisco AnyConnect VPN, I am trying to find my way around their client software and discovered `openconnect`. So far it works great and thanks to a [different question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220380/openconnect-setting-default-routes) here on StackExchange, I managed to make it stop routing all my traffic through the VPN by default and instead only send college-related traffic through the VPN.

However, `openconnect` still sends all my DNS queries to the college's nameserver, as I can read in `/etc/resolv.conf`. Now, because I rather use my own DNS resolver, I want to stop `openconnect` from changing the DNS settings. I can set the `INTERNAL_IP4_DNS` variable which I could dynamically set through the wrapper-script I created for the routing, but that doesn't completely solve my problem, since it still modifies the file and adds the search domain from my college.

Is there a way to stop `openconnect` from doing that without manipulating the vpnc-script?

Comment: Probably telling `dhclient` to not modify resolv.conf, or setting chattr immutable flag for resolv.conf

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I don't want to stop all changes to this file, as it might be necessary when I physically connect to a different network. I only want to stop `openconnect` from making those changes.

Comment: Create a script to connect, do the changes, redo them on exit. A possible approach. Clunky, I agree...

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro That's basically what the vpnc-script does. I guess I could make my own version of it and remove the part where it changes the DNS settings or add a section where it undoes it after connecting. I just thought that there is a more elegant solution, since I don't think this is a rare use-case.

Comment: There is always the change of intercepting DNS requests by iptables and sending them to another place. More complicated, and once again you have got to have a wrapper script.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks, that's another workaround, I could try for now. I do already have a wrapper script for routing.

Answer (score 8):

Posting as an answer rather than a comment to give it some visibility. I am not sure whether there is a better way for just citing other site's answers. But https://serverfault.com/a/900825 is an answer to nearly the same question that actually works.

`openconnect` calls a the script `/usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script` to change network settings (see /usr/share/doc/openconnect/html/vpnc-script.html). But you can change the script called with the `-s` option. If you pass in a script like

```
#!/bin/bash
export INTERNAL_IP4_DNS=
. /usr/share/vpnc-scripts/vpnc-script
```

the function to change `resolv.conf` in the original script is simply not called.

Given the script above is called `noresolvconf`, you would call `openconnect` like

```
sudo openconnect -s path/to/noresolvconf ...
```

Don't forget to make the script executable with

```
chmod +x path/to/noresolvconf
```

Comment: thanks for sharing your solution.